# find and replace / refactoring programmatically for files in mac

Tags: xcode, macos, replace

I want to make a program that will search and replace some words occurrence in a file. I am using xcode. I want to do this programmatically using some standard free API in a MAC application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` or `sed`, which are standard UNIX tools. See this [nice Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/opensource/conceptual/shellscripting/RegularExpressionsUnfettered/RegularExpressionsUnfettered.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004268-CH238-SW7).